# Applying changes to lines in alternating modes

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, range

I know I can apply changes to multiple lines by selecting the lines in visual mode (I use `ctrl-v`) and defining the set of actions and the mode to start in (e.g. `norma A,` will add a comma at the end of all selected lines).

I was wondering how can I go back to normal mode after using something like `A` (which goes to insert mode). I'm not familiar with the terminology enough to google it properly.

I want to add a comma at the end of each line and then join all lines together. I assumed something like the following (not correct, obviously) should do it:

`ctrl-v`, `G`, `:`, `normal A, normal J` `RET`

But obviously this appends `, normal J` to each line.

I know there are plenty of other ways to do it (regular expressions, macros ...) so I don't need alternatives, that's not my question.

Comment: In this particular case, you don't need to use the blockwise selection. Thus you can do the following sequence: `vG:norm! A,^]I+` (where `^]` is the escape character as explained by @Nobe4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well actually you can use a litteral `<ESC>` character to chain commands like you would do normally:

```
:'<,'>norm! A,^II+
```

This will insert a `,` at the end of each line, and a `+` at the start.

To add the special `^I` char, press `C-v` and `ESC`.

Comment: You should use `norm!` instead of `norm`, in order to use standard mappings instead of user defined mappings (if there are conflicts).